# Create Tooltip for SVG <image> tag

Tags: image, svg, tooltip

I am attempting to create a tooltip that will appear when the user hover overs the icon, the tootltip will give information regarding the event. The  tag is within an SVG image.

This is the code for the image:

```
<image  class="tooltip-trigger" data-tooltip-text="Battles" id="Battles" x="100" y="200" width="30" height="30" xlink:href="battle.png" />


<g id="tooltip" visibility="hidden" >
        <rect x="2" y="2" width="80" height="24" fill="black" opacity="0.4" rx="2" ry="2"/>
        <rect width="80" height="24" fill="white" rx="2" ry="2"/>
        <text x="3" y="6">Tooltip</text>
    </g>


<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    (function() {
        var svg = document.getElementById('tooltip-svg-5');
        var tooltip = svg.getElementById('tooltip');
        var tooltipText = tooltip.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].firstChild;
        var triggers = svg.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-trigger');
        for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
            triggers[i].addEventListener('mousemove', showTooltip);
            triggers[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hideTooltip);
        }
        function showTooltip(evt) {
            var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
            var x = (evt.clientX - CTM.e + 6) / CTM.a;
            var y = (evt.clientY - CTM.f + 20) / CTM.d;
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate(" + x + " " + y + ")");
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible");
            tooltipText.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "data-tooltip-text");
        }
        function hideTooltip(evt) {
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "hidden");
        }
    })()
]]></script>
```

When loaded, the tooltip does not appear

Comment: CODE FOR IMAGE: <image  class="tooltip-trigger" data-tooltip-text="Battles" id="Battles" x="100" y="200" width="30" height="30" xlink:href="battle.png" />
    <g id="tooltip" visibility="hidden" >
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="80" height="24" fill="black" opacity="0.4" rx="2" ry="2"/>
  <rect width="80" height="24" fill="white" rx="2" ry="2"/>
  <text x="3" y="6">Tooltip</text>
 </g>

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working. The problem you may have is that the tooltip appears mostly outside the svg element. I've added `overflow:visible;` to the svg element and now you can see the tooltip.

```js
  (function() {
        var svg = document.getElementById('tooltip-svg-5');
        var tooltip = svg.getElementById('tooltip');
        var tooltipText = tooltip.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].firstChild;
        var triggers = svg.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-trigger');
        for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
            triggers[i].addEventListener('mousemove', showTooltip);
            triggers[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hideTooltip);
        }
        function showTooltip(evt) {
            var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
            var x = (evt.clientX - CTM.e + 6) / CTM.a;
            var y = (evt.clientY - CTM.f + 20) / CTM.d;
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate(" + x + " " + y + ")");
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible");
            tooltipText.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "data-tooltip-text");
        }
        function hideTooltip(evt) {
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "hidden");
        }
    })()
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; overflow:visible;display:block;margin:auto}
```

```html
<svg id="tooltip-svg-5" viewBox="0 -8 130 238" width="200">

  <image class="tooltip-trigger" data-tooltip-text="Battles" id="Battles" x="100" y="200" width="30" height="30" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/pin.png" /> 
  <g id="tooltip" visibility="hidden"> 
    <rect x="2" y="2" width="80" height="24" fill="black" opacity="0.4" rx="2" ry="2"/> 
    <rect width="80" height="24" fill="white" rx="2" ry="2"/> 
    <text x="3" y="6">Tooltip</text> 
  </g> 
</svg>
```

Another option would have been adding `text-anchor="end"` to the text and rewriting the rects accordingly.

Yet another potion would have been using an HTML element for the tooltip.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Another issue to that I want the tooltip text to appear in different lines however the <br> is not working: data-tooltip-text=\""+id+"<br/>Location: "+location+"<br/>Result: "+result+" any suggestions?

Comment: You are right. The `<br/>` is not working with svg `<text>`. You will need to use [`<tspan>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan). Please try something like this:  `<svg id="tooltip-svg-5" viewBox="0 -20 150 90" width="200">
  <g id="tooltip"> 
    <text x="3" y="6">27
    <tspan x="3" dy="19">Location: Barcelona</tspan>
    <tspan x="3" dy="19">Result: result</tspan>
    </text> 
  </g> 
</svg>`.  If this is not helping please ask a different question.