# Interactive SVG map Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

First post and new programmer. I'm trying to get a tooltip displaying a text of a country when it is scrolled over.

I have an SVG of a world map that is of the form

```
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="CN"
     data-name="China"
     data-id="CN"
     d="m 1587.2,453.3 0.6,-3.6 2,-2.8 -1.6,-2.5 -3.2,-0.1 -5.8,1.8 -2.2,2.8 1,5.5 4.9,2 4.3,-3.1 z m 13.2,-196.5 -6.1,-6.1 -4.4,-3.7 -3.8,-2.7 -7.7,-6.1 -5.9,-2.3 -8.5,-1.8 -6.2,0.2 -5.1,1.1 -1.7,3 3.7,1.5 2.5,3.3 -1.2,2 0.1,6.5 1.9,2.7 -4.4,3.9 -7.3,-2.3 0.6,4.6 0.3,6.2 2.7,2.6 2.4,-0.8 5.4,1 2.5,-2.3 5.1,2 7.2,4.3 0.7,2.2 -4.3,-0.7 -6.8,0.8 -2.4,1.8 -1.4,4.1 -6.3,2.4 -3.1,3.3 -5.9,-1.3 -3.2,-0.5 -0.4,4 2.9,2.3 1.9,2.1 -2.5,2 -1.9,3.3 -4.9,2.2 -7.5,0.2 -7.2,2.2 -4.4,3.3 -3.2,-2 -6.2,0.1 -9.3,-3.8 -5.5,-0.9 -6.4,0.8 -11.2,-1.3 -5.5,0.1 -4.7,-3.6 -4.9,-5.7 -3.4,-0.7 -7.9,-3.8 -7.2,-0.9 -6.4,-1 -3,-2.7 -1.3,-7.3 -5.8,-5 -8.1,-2.3 -5.7,-3.3 -3.3,-4.4 -1.7,0.5 -1.8,4.2 -3.8,0.6 2.5,6.2 -1.6,2.8 -10.7,-2 1,11.1 -2,1.4 -9,2.4 8.7,10.7 -2.9,1.6 1.7,3.5 -0.2,1.4 -6.8,3.4 -1,2.4 -6.4,0.8 -0.6,4 -5.7,-0.9 -3.2,1.2 -4,3 1.1,1.5 -1,1.5 3,5.9 1.6,-0.6 3.5,1.4 0.6,2.5 1.8,3.7 1.4,1.9 4.7,3 2.9,5 9.4,2.6 7.6,7.5 0.8,5.2 3,3.3 0.6,3.3 -4.1,-0.9 3.2,7 6.2,4 8.5,4.4 1.9,-1.5 4.7,2 6.4,4.1 3.2,0.9 2.5,3.1 4.5,1.2 5,2.8 6.4,1.5 6.5,0.6 3,-1.4 1.5,5.1 2.6,-4.8 2.6,-1.6 4.2,1.5 2.9,0.1 2.7,1.8 4.2,-0.8 3.9,-4.8 5.3,-4 4.9,1.5 3.2,-2.6 3.5,3.9 -1.2,2.7 6.1,0.9 3,-0.4 2.7,3.7 2.7,1.5 1.3,4.9 0.8,5.3 -4.1,5.3 0.7,7.5 5.6,-1 2.3,5.8 3.7,1.3 -0.8,5.2 4.5,2.4 2.5,1.2 3.8,-1.8 0.6,2.6 0.7,1.5 2.9,0.1 -1.9,-7.2 2.7,-1 2.7,-1.5 4.3,0 5.3,-0.7 4.1,-3.4 3,2.4 5.2,1.1 -0.2,3.7 3,2.6 5.9,1.6 2.4,-1 7.7,2 -0.9,2.5 2.2,4.6 3,-0.4 0.8,-6.7 5.6,-0.9 7.2,-3.2 2.5,-3.2 2.3,2.1 2.8,-2.9 6.1,-0.7 6.6,-5.3 6.3,-5.9 3.3,-7.6 2.3,-8.4 2.1,-6.9 2.8,-0.5 -0.1,-5.1 -0.8,-5.1 -3.8,-2 -2.5,-3.4 2.8,-1.7 -1.6,-4.7 -5.4,-4.9 -5.4,-5.8 -4.6,-6.3 -7.1,-3.5 0.9,-4.6 3.8,-3.2 1,-3.5 6.7,-1.8 -2.4,-3.4 -3.4,-0.2 -5.8,-2.5 -3.9,4.6 -4.9,-1.9 -1.5,-2.9 -4.7,-1 -4.7,-4.4 1.2,-3 5,-0.3 1.2,-4.1 3.6,-4.4 3.4,-2.2 4.4,3.3 -1.9,4.2 2.3,2.5 -1.4,3 4.8,-1.8 2.4,-2.9 6.3,-1.9 2.1,-4 3.8,-3.4 1,-4.4 3.6,2 4.6,0.2 -2.7,-3.3 6.3,-2.6 -0.1,-3.5 5.5,3.6 0,0 -1.9,-3.1 2.5,-0.1 -3.8,-7.3 -4.7,-5.3 2.9,-2.2 6.8,1.1 -0.6,-6 -2.8,-6.8 0.4,-2.3 -1.3,-5.6 -6.9,1.8 -2.6,2.5 -7.5,0 -6,-5.8 -8.9,-4.5 -9.9,-1.9 z"
     style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-rule:evenodd" />
```

For example.

My approach was at the end of the SVG file to add the following:

```
 <text class="label" id="country-name" x="10" y="390"></text>

        <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
function displayName(name) {
    document.getElementById('country-name').firstChild.data = name;
}
]]></script>
```

I thought this would select the element with country-name and then set the value to equal the passed name. In the SVG file I then edited it for example like this (I've omitted the ending tag from the code snippet):

```
path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="Algeria"
     onmouseover="displayName('Algeria')"
```

When I then load the SVG the text doesn't display.

I saw another post: [Create Tooltip for SVG <image> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058529/create-tooltip-for-svg-image-tag)

I tried adding the overflow:visible; but this also doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use textContent to set the content of a text element. I've also moved the text x and y so they are closer to the shape.

```html
<svg viewBox="1000 100 1000 600">
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     onmouseover="displayName('China')"
     id="CN"
     data-name="China"
     data-id="CN"
     d="m 1587.2,453.3 0.6,-3.6 2,-2.8 -1.6,-2.5 -3.2,-0.1 -5.8,1.8 -2.2,2.8 1,5.5 4.9,2 4.3,-3.1 z m 13.2,-196.5 -6.1,-6.1 -4.4,-3.7 -3.8,-2.7 -7.7,-6.1 -5.9,-2.3 -8.5,-1.8 -6.2,0.2 -5.1,1.1 -1.7,3 3.7,1.5 2.5,3.3 -1.2,2 0.1,6.5 1.9,2.7 -4.4,3.9 -7.3,-2.3 0.6,4.6 0.3,6.2 2.7,2.6 2.4,-0.8 5.4,1 2.5,-2.3 5.1,2 7.2,4.3 0.7,2.2 -4.3,-0.7 -6.8,0.8 -2.4,1.8 -1.4,4.1 -6.3,2.4 -3.1,3.3 -5.9,-1.3 -3.2,-0.5 -0.4,4 2.9,2.3 1.9,2.1 -2.5,2 -1.9,3.3 -4.9,2.2 -7.5,0.2 -7.2,2.2 -4.4,3.3 -3.2,-2 -6.2,0.1 -9.3,-3.8 -5.5,-0.9 -6.4,0.8 -11.2,-1.3 -5.5,0.1 -4.7,-3.6 -4.9,-5.7 -3.4,-0.7 -7.9,-3.8 -7.2,-0.9 -6.4,-1 -3,-2.7 -1.3,-7.3 -5.8,-5 -8.1,-2.3 -5.7,-3.3 -3.3,-4.4 -1.7,0.5 -1.8,4.2 -3.8,0.6 2.5,6.2 -1.6,2.8 -10.7,-2 1,11.1 -2,1.4 -9,2.4 8.7,10.7 -2.9,1.6 1.7,3.5 -0.2,1.4 -6.8,3.4 -1,2.4 -6.4,0.8 -0.6,4 -5.7,-0.9 -3.2,1.2 -4,3 1.1,1.5 -1,1.5 3,5.9 1.6,-0.6 3.5,1.4 0.6,2.5 1.8,3.7 1.4,1.9 4.7,3 2.9,5 9.4,2.6 7.6,7.5 0.8,5.2 3,3.3 0.6,3.3 -4.1,-0.9 3.2,7 6.2,4 8.5,4.4 1.9,-1.5 4.7,2 6.4,4.1 3.2,0.9 2.5,3.1 4.5,1.2 5,2.8 6.4,1.5 6.5,0.6 3,-1.4 1.5,5.1 2.6,-4.8 2.6,-1.6 4.2,1.5 2.9,0.1 2.7,1.8 4.2,-0.8 3.9,-4.8 5.3,-4 4.9,1.5 3.2,-2.6 3.5,3.9 -1.2,2.7 6.1,0.9 3,-0.4 2.7,3.7 2.7,1.5 1.3,4.9 0.8,5.3 -4.1,5.3 0.7,7.5 5.6,-1 2.3,5.8 3.7,1.3 -0.8,5.2 4.5,2.4 2.5,1.2 3.8,-1.8 0.6,2.6 0.7,1.5 2.9,0.1 -1.9,-7.2 2.7,-1 2.7,-1.5 4.3,0 5.3,-0.7 4.1,-3.4 3,2.4 5.2,1.1 -0.2,3.7 3,2.6 5.9,1.6 2.4,-1 7.7,2 -0.9,2.5 2.2,4.6 3,-0.4 0.8,-6.7 5.6,-0.9 7.2,-3.2 2.5,-3.2 2.3,2.1 2.8,-2.9 6.1,-0.7 6.6,-5.3 6.3,-5.9 3.3,-7.6 2.3,-8.4 2.1,-6.9 2.8,-0.5 -0.1,-5.1 -0.8,-5.1 -3.8,-2 -2.5,-3.4 2.8,-1.7 -1.6,-4.7 -5.4,-4.9 -5.4,-5.8 -4.6,-6.3 -7.1,-3.5 0.9,-4.6 3.8,-3.2 1,-3.5 6.7,-1.8 -2.4,-3.4 -3.4,-0.2 -5.8,-2.5 -3.9,4.6 -4.9,-1.9 -1.5,-2.9 -4.7,-1 -4.7,-4.4 1.2,-3 5,-0.3 1.2,-4.1 3.6,-4.4 3.4,-2.2 4.4,3.3 -1.9,4.2 2.3,2.5 -1.4,3 4.8,-1.8 2.4,-2.9 6.3,-1.9 2.1,-4 3.8,-3.4 1,-4.4 3.6,2 4.6,0.2 -2.7,-3.3 6.3,-2.6 -0.1,-3.5 5.5,3.6 0,0 -1.9,-3.1 2.5,-0.1 -3.8,-7.3 -4.7,-5.3 2.9,-2.2 6.8,1.1 -0.6,-6 -2.8,-6.8 0.4,-2.3 -1.3,-5.6 -6.9,1.8 -2.6,2.5 -7.5,0 -6,-5.8 -8.9,-4.5 -9.9,-1.9 z"
     style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-rule:evenodd" />
      <text class="label" id="country-name" x="1200" y="300"></text>

        <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
function displayName(name) {
    document.getElementById('country-name').textContent = name;
}
]]></script>
</svg>
```